# finding nth biggest element in multidimensional array

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array, data-science

how can I find *5th* or *7th*, or *15th* biggest element in multidimensional array without existing methods (like `list.Add`)
I will be pleased if you write it in c#

```
int[,,,] x =new int[100, 20, 35, 200];

...

int indis  = 0;
int toplam = 0;
int enss   = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
    toplam = 0;

    for (int k = 0; k < 35; k++) {
      for (int l = 0; l < 200; l++) {
        toplam += x[i, j, k, l];
      }
    }

    if (toplam > enss) {
      enss  = toplam; 
      indis = j;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Use quickselect to get the k'th biggest element in expected linear time. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect

Answer (score 1):

You can try to *query* with a help of *Linq* (let .NET use `Add` if it wants). The *crucial thing* is to treat multidimensional array `T[,,,]` as `IEnumerable<T>`; we can use [OfType()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=net-7.0&ranMID=43674&ranEAID=FE4O7wtxe6g&ranSiteID=FE4O7wtxe6g-9j8K3wojZgCxt9iGf5GnEQ&epi=FE4O7wtxe6g-9j8K3wojZgCxt9iGf5GnEQ&irgwc=1&OCID=AID2200057_aff_7795_1243925&tduid=(ir__1impw2s6cwkfb29c0gcpuf19xn2xqb2rj1j2t3qu00)(7795)(1243925)(FE4O7wtxe6g-9j8K3wojZgCxt9iGf5GnEQ)()&irclickid=_1impw2s6cwkfb29c0gcpuf19xn2xqb2rj1j2t3qu00) for this. Having `IEnumerable<T>` we can solve the rest. To find max item, just call `Max()`:

```
using System.Linq;

...

int[,,,] x = new int[100, 20, 35, 200];

...

int max = x.OfType<int>().Max();
```

If you want to find `n`th biggest item, you can sort, skip `n - 1` items and take the first:

```
...

int n = 7;

int maxN = x
  .OfType<int>()
  .OrderByDescending(item => item)
  .Skip(n - 1)
  .First();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using linq :

```
           var table = Enumerable.Range(0, x.GetLength(0))
                .SelectMany((a, i) => Enumerable.Range(0, x.GetLength(1))
                .SelectMany((b, j) => Enumerable.Range(0, x.GetLength(2))
                .SelectMany((c, k) => Enumerable.Range(0, x.GetLength(3)
                .Select((d, l) => new { x = x[i, j, k, l], i = i, j = j, k = k, l = l }))))
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.x);
```